# F# money allocation headache

Tags: f#

I have one question:

```
let totalAmount = 1400.0M
let allocations = [| 0.45M; 0.45M; 0.1M |]
let minAmount = 250.0M
```

Let’s assume there is $1400 to allocate to 3 parties, the minimum amount to allocate is $250; and each party has different percentage of the total amount.  Here Party A & B will get 45% of the total amount, and Party C will get 10%, the allocated amount has to be number of times of the minimum amount.
I want to write a function to get the result:

```
let allocated = [| 500.0M; 500.0M; 250.0M |]
```

But I can not figure out a good way for the function.  The issue is: for Party C, the amount of 10% of $1400 is only $140, which is less than $250, but since the Party A and B each has only $500, therefore, there is still $400 left, so Party C can still have $250 the minimum amount.
If you have a good idea, please show me your code.
Thanks,
John

Comment: So `allocated.[n]` is the multiple of `minAmount` that makes `allocated.[n]` as near as possible to `allocations.[n] * totalAmount`? It’s hard to tell what you’re asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am newbie to F# and this is my first attempt to solve F# question so take it easy with me..:). Hey but it works

**Code:**

```
let HandOutMoney (totalAmount:decimal) (allocations:decimal[]) (minAmount:decimal) =
    let possibleMinimumAllocations (int) =  totalAmount/minAmount
    let allocateMoney = allocations |> Array.map(fun p ->  p * totalAmount / minAmount) |> Array.map int |> Array.map(fun x -> if x = 0 then 1 else x) |> Array.map decimal
    let finalallocateMoney = allocateMoney  |> Array.map(fun p -> p * minAmount)
    finalallocateMoney
```

**Input values:**

```
let totalAmount = 1400.0M
let allocations = [| 0.45M; 0.45M; 0.1M |]
let minAmount = 250.0M
```

**Output:**

```
HandOutMoney totalAmount allocations minAmount

val it : decimal [] = [|500.0M; 500.0M; 250.0M|]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your code works and it is very functional!
I have figured out a non-functional way, but your code looks better, I will use your code.
Thanks again for your kind help!
John

Comment: Glad. i could help. bring it on more F# :D

Answer (score 2):

How about this (see inlined comments for description of algorithm):

```
let handoutMoney totalAmount allocations minAmount =
    //the general approach is to start off giving each party the 
    //minAmount, and then from there dividing up the remaining 
    //totalAmount proportionally by allocation for those parties 
    //that have not exceeded their original allocation

    //with respect to minAmount, map under-allocated as Some, 
    //and over-allocated as None
    let underAllocated =
        allocations 
        |> Array.map (fun pct -> 
            if pct * totalAmount > minAmount then Some(pct) else None)

    //Sum all the under-allocated percentages, we will use this
    //to recalculate percentages for remaining allocations beyond 
    //the minAmount
    let remainingAllocationTotal =
        underAllocated
        |> Array.sumBy (function | Some(pct) -> pct | None -> 0.0M)

    //Now using the remainingAllocationTotal we can adjust the 
    //underAllocated allocations so that the remaining amount 
    //after the min amount is subtracted can be proportionally allocated
    let remainingAllocations =
        underAllocated
        |> Array.map (function 
            | Some(pct) -> (pct / remainingAllocationTotal)
            | None -> 0.0M)

    //the amount leftover from the totalAmount after the subtracting 
    //the minAmount which was given to each party
    let remainingAmount =
        totalAmount - (minAmount * decimal allocations.Length)

    //tie it all together: add the minAmount to the remainingAllocation 
    //pct times the remainingAmount
    remainingAllocations
    |> Array.map (fun pct ->
        minAmount + (pct * remainingAmount))
```

Then given your example we'd have:

```
> handoutMoney totalAmount allocations minAmount;;
val it : decimal [] =
  [|575.00000000000000000000000000M; 575.00000000000000000000000000M; 250.0M|]
```

(I'm not really sure where you came up with $500 being allocated to party A & B in your example, but I believe the algorithm I've presented is a reasonable approach to the problem as I understand it)

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your explanation and code.
However, I need the allocated fund to be integer number of times of minAmount; but the result from your function for Party A & B is $575, and $575/$250 = 2.3.  Therefore, it is not what I want, I want Party A & B is $500, as $500/$250 = 2 and 2 is integer.

It seems the question is not easy to find the answer.  I will try to use the non-functional way to figure it out first, then try to use functional way.